# How to Navigate different pages in flutter Curvednavigationbar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-navigation

I am trying to add different page routing Navigation in Curvednavigationbar insider I tried some different ways But it doesn't work

I'm Using `curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.1` for bottomNavigation bar.

I was tried different ways but it doesn't work.

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  List<dynamic> _page = [
    Add(),
    Copyright(),
    HomePage(),
  ];
  int _activePage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          index: _activePage,
          height: 60.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _page[index][1]));
          },
          letIndexChange: (index) => true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: _page[_activePage],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the page index rather then pushing to new page

```
onTap: (index) {
               setState(() { _activePage=index});
              },
```

Comment: I tried it Shows "Error: Assertion failed:"

Comment: try body:  _page[_activePage] only

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Below example  that i have created from the example that you have posted:

```
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: BottomNavBar(),
  ));
}

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  List<dynamic> _page = [
    Add(),
    Copyright(),
    HomePage(),
  ];
  int _activePage = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("This is the actice page $_activePage");
    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
          index: _activePage,
          height: 60.0,
          items: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.add, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.list, size: 30),
            Icon(Icons.compare_arrows, size: 30),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
          animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
          animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          onTap: (index) {
            setState(() {
              _activePage = index;
            });
            print("Index : $index active : $_activePage");
            // you don't need this as the bottom nav is doing it for you just have to specify index
            // Navigator.push(context,
            //     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _page[_activePage]));
          },
          letIndexChange: (index) => true,
        ),
        body: Container(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Center(
            child: _page[_activePage],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class Add extends StatelessWidget {
  const Add({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Add Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Copyright extends StatelessWidget {
  const Copyright({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Copy Right Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Home Page"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You do not have to use the Navigator as the bottom Navigator does the task for you, you just have to pass the index and rebuild the page using the setstate method

Check the example and let me know if it works

Comment: Working in separately but in project it doesn't work?  "Error: Assertion failed:"

Comment: This is the actice page 32
Error: Assertion failed:
_debugCurrentBuildTarget == context
is not true
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:56717/dart_sdk.js:5041:11)
    at Object.assertFailed (http://localhost:56717/dart_sdk.js:4980:15)
    at http://localhost:56717/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:49503:83
    at framework.BuildOwner.new.buildScope (http://localhost:56717/packages/flutter/src/widgets/widget_span.dart.lib.js:49507:32)
    at RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.new.attachToRenderTree )

Comment: when are you getting this error when you change the pages, and is there any loader for the page when data is loaded this is my query or you are trying to run this on the web